# How to remove not equals Objects using ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

If I have an ArrayList of books and I want to delete a certain number of books only if they are different (using equals). How can I approach the problem?

For example, if I have 3 different books and my `quantitytoremove` is 3.. then those 3 books have to be deleted. Assuming `quantitytoremove` can't be higher than the number of DIFFERENT books inside the array.

I tried something like this but I know there are issues with what I wrote. Is there a function available with streams or else that can help me?

```java
   public Basket removeDifferent(int quantitytoremove) {
        int removed=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.numberBooks && removed<quantitytoremove ; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < this.numberBooks && removed<quantitytoremove; j++) {
                if (!(this.BooksArray.get(i).equals(this.BooksArray.get(j)))) {

                    Book Book_i= this.BooksArray.get(i);
                    Book Book_j= this.BooksArray.get(j);
                    this.BooksArray.remove(Book_i);
                    this.BooksArray.remove(Book_j);

                    removed=removed+2;
                    this.numberBooks=numberBooks-2;
                    i=0;j=1;

                }

            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `Set` instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i need to keep it as a ArrayList, is that possible with a Set?

Comment: Well, you could take the `ArrayList`, put it through the `Set` which will keep only unquie instances of the object and then put that back into a `ArrayList` ... so yes

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase.

Comment: @MadProgrammer what is the function suitable for this operation using Set?

Comment: [Documentation, documentation, documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) - start by reading the JavaDocs, have a look at the avaliable implementations and their properties and see which ones you can fit into your needs

Comment: Suppose you have an `ArrayList` with the following books inside: `book1, book2, book3, book1, book4`, and `quantitytoremove` is 4.
What is the **output** you would like to have in this case?
What I don't understand is: how should the algorithm behave in case there are **more than 1 of the same book** in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Hazel I don't get it at all. Why should book1 and book1 be removed if they are not different?

Comment: @AlbertoUrsino Assume that quantitytoremove will never be higher than the amount of different books.. so in that case quantitytoremove can have the value of 1 or 2. in case where there are more than 1 of the same book in the ArrayList.. for example book1 book1 book1 book2 book3, and the quantitytoremove is 2, then book1 and book2 (for example) should be deleted

Comment: @Ecto sorry typo :(

Comment: @Hazel ok, it's clear now, are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Ecto im currently trying all the answers in here lol

Comment: @Hazel ok, let me know how it goes, btw in your example where you remove 2 from `book1 book1 book1 book2 book3` , afterwards remaining books are `book1 book1 book3` or `book3`? (does it remove one instance of each book or all books of same type)

Comment: @Ecto yeah exactly, one instance of each book

Comment: Does the algorithm choose at random which books to remove?

Comment: @AlbertoUrsino yes its random, but it only removes 1 instance of the books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, @Override equals() in class Foo to decide what's the attributes that make two objects equals and remove using `recursion`

> Explain how recursion works

`qn` represents how many removes are done

**Starting point** `i = 0` `j = 1` and recursion till the base condition reached

**Step 1, Base condition**: if `i` or `j` exceeded the size of the array or `qn` exceeded the `quantityToRemove` return `qn`

**Step 2, Check equality** if array elements of `i` and `j` not equal then remove and increment `qn` and decrement `j` to avoid missing element

**Step 3** for all `i` and increment `j` Repeat to Step 3 till reaching the base condition

**Step 4** increment `++i`

**Step 5** start new recursion with increment `i` and start `j` from `i+1`

After the recussion has finished, check if `qn` not exceeded the `quantityToRemove` and remove from the array if contains 1 book. this for a case when you have different 4 books and want all of them to be removed

...

**Trace**

i = 0, j = 1, 2, ...., N

i = 1, j = 2, 3, ...., N

i = 2, j = 3, 4, ...., N

i = 3, j = 4, 5, ...., N

...

```
   static class Book {
        int id;
        String title;

        public Book(int id, String title) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Book other = (Book) obj;
            return this.title.equals(other.title);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + ": " + title;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Book b1 = new Book(1, "b1");
        Book b2 = new Book(2, "b2");
        Book b3 = new Book(3, "b3");
        Book b4 = new Book(4, "b4");
        Book b5 = new Book(1, "b1");
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(b1);
        list.add(b2);
        list.add(b3);
        list.add(b4);
        list.add(b5);
        list.add(new Book(1, "b1"));
        list.add(new Book(1, "b1"));
        list.add(new Book(1, "b1"));

        System.out.println(list);
        removeDifferent(list, 2);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    static void removeDifferent(List<Book> booksArray, int quantityToRemove) {
        int qn = removeDifferent(booksArray, quantityToRemove, 0, 0, 1);
        if (booksArray.size() == 1 && qn < quantityToRemove)
            booksArray.remove(0);
    }

    static int removeDifferent(List<Book> booksArray, int quantityToRemove, int qn, int i, int j) {
        if (i >= booksArray.size() || j >= booksArray.size() || qn >= quantityToRemove)
            return qn;
        if (!booksArray.get(i).equals(booksArray.get(j))) {
            booksArray.remove(j);
            j--;
            qn++;
        }
        qn = removeDifferent(booksArray, quantityToRemove, qn, i, 1 + j);
        ++i;
        qn = removeDifferent(booksArray, quantityToRemove, qn, i, i + 1);
        return qn;
    }
```

, output

```
[1: b1, 2: b2, 3: b3, 4: b4, 1: b1, 1: b1, 1: b1, 1: b1]
[1: b1, 4: b4, 1: b1, 1: b1, 1: b1, 1: b1]
```

, And for this input

```
        Book b1 = new Book(1, "b1");
        Book b2 = new Book(2, "b2");
        Book b3 = new Book(3, "b3");
        Book b4 = new Book(4, "b4");
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(b1);
        list.add(b2);
        list.add(b3);
        list.add(b4);
        System.out.println(list);
        removeDifferent(list, 4);
        System.out.println(list);
```

, output

```
[]
```

Comment: what if there is book1 book2 and book3, & quantityToRemove=3. I think there will be one left  not removed no?

Comment: if they are different yes will be removed

Comment: i tried it and no, if your list contains 3 different books and i call removeDifferent(list, 3); there will be 1 book left not deleted

Comment: Did you try the recursion solution?

Comment: seems to work :)  but it makes me really dizzy thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Steps to be followed:

1. Put `bookList` into a `Set` to remove the duplicate elements and then create a `List`, `books` out of the `Set`.
2. Add `quantityToRemove` elements from `books` to another `List`, `toBeRemovedList`.
3. Add all elements, except one item each also belonging to `tobeRemovedList` from `bookList` to another `List`, `toBeReturnedList`.

**Note:** You can replace the first step using `Stream` API as shown below:

```
static List<Book> removeDifferent(List<Book> bookList, int quantityToRemove) {
    // Put `bookList` into a Set to remove the duplicate elements and then create
    // a List, `books` out of the Set
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(new HashSet<Book>(bookList));

    // You can replace the above code with Stream code given below:
    // List<Book> books = bookList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Add `quantityToRemove` elements from `books` to another List,
    // `toBeRemovedList`
    List<Book> toBeRemovedList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for (int i = 0; i < quantityToRemove; i++) {
        toBeRemovedList.add(books.get(i));
    }

    // Add all elements, except one item each also belonging to `tobeRemovedList`
    // from `bookList` to another List, `toBeReturnedList`
    List<Book> toBeReturnedList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    int c = 0;// Counter
    for (Book book : toBeRemovedList) {
        for (int i = c; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
            if (book.equals(bookList.get(i))) {
                c = i;
                break;
            }
            toBeReturnedList.add(bookList.get(i));
        }
        c++;
    }
    for (int i = c; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
        toBeReturnedList.add(bookList.get(i));
    }

    // Return toBeReturnedList
    return toBeReturnedList;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

class Book {
    int id;

    public Book(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        return this.id == other.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        books.add(new Book(1));
        books.add(new Book(1));
        books.add(new Book(1));
        books.add(new Book(2));
        books.add(new Book(3));

        List<Book> updatedList = removeDifferent(books, 3);

        // Display updated list
        updatedList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static List<Book> removeDifferent(List<Book> bookList, int quantityToRemove) {
        // Put `bookList` into a Set to remove the duplicate elements and then create
        // a List, `books` out of the Set
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(new HashSet<Book>(bookList));

        // You can replace the above code with Stream code given below:
        // List<Book> books = bookList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Add `quantityToRemove` elements from `books` to another List,
        // `toBeRemovedList`
        List<Book> toBeRemovedList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for (int i = 0; i < quantityToRemove; i++) {
            toBeRemovedList.add(books.get(i));
        }

        // Add all elements, except one item each also belonging to `tobeRemovedList`
        // from `bookList` to another List, `toBeReturnedList`
        List<Book> toBeReturnedList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        int c = 0;// Counter
        for (Book book : toBeRemovedList) {
            for (int i = c; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
                if (book.equals(bookList.get(i))) {
                    c = i;
                    break;
                }
                toBeReturnedList.add(bookList.get(i));
            }
            c++;
        }
        for (int i = c; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
            toBeReturnedList.add(bookList.get(i));
        }

        // Return toBeReturnedList
        return toBeReturnedList;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Book [id=1]
Book [id=1]
```

**Result for `removeDifferent(books, 2)`:**

```
Book [id=1]
Book [id=1]
Book [id=3]
```

**Result for `removeDifferent(books, 1)`:**

```
Book [id=1]
Book [id=1]
Book [id=2]
Book [id=3]
```

Comment: this dosn't work if i have 3 different books and my quantitytoremove is 3

Comment: For example, if i have 3 different books and my quantitytoremove is 3.. then those 3 books have to be deleted.

Comment: it depends on quantitytoremove, 3 should be removed if quantitytoremove = 3

Comment: if quantitytoremove =1, then only 1 should be deleted so i thing there is a condition missinfg in the loops. and no its not me

Comment: `if quantitytoremove =1, then only 1 should be deleted` - The solution perfectly fulfils this requirement. Do you want me to provide some example?

Comment: no because it will keep adding different books in the tobeRemovedList until there is none left. But it needs to stop if i specify quantitytoremove =1, only 1 should be removed. i think the function miss this :&& tobeRemovedList.size()<quantitytoremove

Comment: @Hazel - After checking your last response to Ecto [`@Ecto yeah exactly, one instance of each book `], I've updated the answer again. Hopefully, it meets your requirement.

Comment: @Hazel - I've updated my answer with the output of the demo program. I've also mentioned the output for a couple of more tests which are  `removeDifferent(books, 2)` and `removeDifferent(books, 1)`. As far as I understood the requirement, the test results satisfy them. However, until you test and approve it, I'll assume it's not done.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Stream and removeIf：

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
// init the books
List<Book> distinctBooks = books.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
int quantitytoremove = 3;
List<Book> needToDeleted = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < quantitytoremove; i++) {
    needToDeleted.add(distinctBooks.get(i));
}

books.removeIf(needToDeleted::contains);
System.out.println(books);
```