# Remove different Objects from Java ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have already asked this question in this post :[How to remove not equals Objects using ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646691/how-to-remove-not-equals-objects-using-arraylist-in-java)

But there are some cases where the proposed solution does not works. I have tried 2 of them.
What i want to do is quite simple to say but when i start to express it in code.. it gets messy.

> I have an ArrayList of books and I want to delete a certain number of
>   books only if they are different (using equals).
>
> For example, if I have 3 different books and my quantitytoremove is
>   3.. then those 3 books have to be deleted. Assuming quantitytoremove can't be higher than the number of **DIFFERENT** books inside the
>   array. In cases where there are more than 1 of the same book in the
>   ArrayList.. for example `book1 book1 book1 book2 book3`, and the
>   `quantitytoremove` is 2, then `book1 and book2` (for example) should
>   be deleted. The output would be `book1 book1 book3`. **Only one instance of a different book should be deleted**

note that `equals` was overrided correctly.

**This is my first solution** (the more logical for me)

```
public Basket removeDifferent2(int quantitytoremove) {
    System.out.println("looking at the basket before removal... of " + quantitytoremove + " different books");
    printBasket();

    // creating a copy of the books array
    List<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(this.Books));
    // list of books to remove
    List<Book> tobeRemovedList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    // removing books from the basket according to quantitytoremove.
    for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size() && tobeRemovedList.size() < quantitytoremove; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < myBooks.size() && tobeRemovedList.size() < quantitytoremove; j++) {
            if (!(myBooks.get(i).equals(myBooks.get(j)))
                    && !tobeRemovedList.contains(myBooks.get(j))) {
                System.out.println("Removing  Book " + myBooks.get(j).getbooknumber() + " from the basket");
                tobeRemovedList.add(myBooks.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
    myBooks = removeList(myBooks, tobeRemovedList);
    // case where there is one book left to remove that was not considered in the
    // previous loops
    if (tobeRemovedList.size() < quantitytoremove && myBooks.size() == 1) {
        System.out.println("Removing  Book " + myBooks.get(0).getbooknumber() + " from the basket");
        myBooks.remove(myBooks.get(0));
    }

    // creating the new basket without the removed books
    Book[] newbooks = new Book[myBooks.size()];
    newbooks = myBooks.toArray(newbooks);
    Basket newbasket = new Basket(newbooks);

    return newbasket;
}

private List<Book>  removeList(List<Book> list,List<Book> toRemove) {
    for (Book b : toRemove) {
        list.remove(b);
    }

    return list;
}
```

**This is another one i have tried**

```
public Basket removeDifferent(int quantityToRemove) {
    System.out.println("looking at the basket before removal... of " + quantityToRemove + " different books");
    printBasket();
    // creating a copy of the books array
    List<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(this.Books));
    int qn = removeDifferent(myBooks, quantityToRemove, 0, 0, 1);
    if (myBooks.size() == 1 && qn < quantityToRemove)
    myBooks.remove(0);
    // creating the new basket 
    Book[] newbooks = new Book[myBooks.size()];
    newbooks = myBooks.toArray(newbooks);
    Basket newbasket = new Basket(newbooks);

    return newbasket;
}

private int removeDifferent(List<Book> booksArray, int quantityToRemove, int qn, int i, int j) {
    if (i >= booksArray.size() || j >= booksArray.size() || qn >= quantityToRemove)
        return qn;
    if (!booksArray.get(i).equals(booksArray.get(j))) {
        System.out.println("Removing  Book " + booksArray.get(j).getbooknumber() + " from the basket");
        booksArray.remove(j);
        j--;
        qn++;
    }
    qn = removeDifferent(booksArray, quantityToRemove, qn, i, 1 + j);
    ++i;
    qn = removeDifferent(booksArray, quantityToRemove, qn, i, i + 1);
    return qn;
}
```

now in this case it fails and it's hard for me to understand why. As you can see, there is one removal missing, and the basket should be looking something like this after the removal of 3 different books:

Book number 1

```
Book mybook1 = new Book(1);
Book mybook2 = new Book(2);
Book mybook3 = new Book(3);
Book mybook4 = new Book(4);
Book mybook5 = new Book(5);

Book[] books = { mybook1,mybook1,mybook4, mybook5 };
Basket basket = new Basket(books);

Basket newbasket= basket.removeDifferent(3);
System.out.println("printing current basket..");
newbasket.printBasket();
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also add the `Book` and `Basket` code to make your example runnable?

Comment: @MaksimIakunin it's gonna be too much for a post, but those are extremly basic classes a book only have a number and Basket got an array. thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest algorithm is to keep track of the books that you've removed and check against that set before removing each subsequent book. I'll express it as a static method as I don't know the inner working of your `Basket` class.

```java
public static List<Book> removeDifferent(List<Book> books, int quantity) {
    List<Book> removals = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for (Book book : books) {
        if (!removals.contains(book)) { // contains uses .equals().
            removals.add(book);
            quantity--;
            if (quantity == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    List<Book> result = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(books));
    for (Book removal : removals) {
        result.remove(removal);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this wont work because .removeAll(removals) will remove all instances of the specified books

Comment: @Hazel, right you are, edited. luckily remove() only removes the first occurrence.

Comment: but that's looks like to be the same thing as my solution no?

Comment: Both solutions have a significant amount of additional complexity that could be introducing bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I've got an elegant solution using Java Stream API without any counters and argument mutations:

```java
public Basket removeDifferent(int removeCount) {
    final ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<>(this.books);

    new HashSet<>(this.books)
        .stream()
        .limit(removeCount)
        .forEach(list::remove);

    return new Basket(list);
}
```

This method works even if `removeCount` is more than number of different books inside the array.

You can throw an exception if needed:

```java
public Basket removeDifferent(int removeCount) {
    final Set<Book> set = new HashSet<>(this.books);
    if (removeCount > set.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "removeCount cannot be greater than number of different books"
        );
    }

    final ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<>(this.books);
    set.stream().limit(removeCount).forEach(list::remove);

    return new Basket(list);
}
```

Complete runnable example:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book mybook1 = new Book(1);
        Book mybook2 = new Book(2);
        Book mybook3 = new Book(3);
        Book mybook4 = new Book(4);
        Book mybook5 = new Book(5);

        Book[] books = { mybook1,mybook1,mybook4,mybook4, mybook5 };
        Basket basket = new Basket(books);

        Basket newbasket = basket.removeDifferent(5);
        System.out.println("printing current basket..");
        newbasket.printBasket();
    }

    public static class Book {
        private final int number;

        public Book(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getbooknumber() {
            return this.number;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
            Book book = (Book) o;
            return number == book.number;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(number);
        }
    }

    public static class Basket {
        private final List<Book> books;

        public Basket(Collection<Book> books) {
            this(new ArrayList<>(books));
        }

        public Basket(Book[] books) {
            this(Arrays.asList(books));
        }

        public Basket(List<Book> books) {
            this.books = books;
        }

        public Basket removeDifferent(int removeCount) {
            final ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<>(this.books);

            new HashSet<>(this.books)
                .stream()
                .limit(removeCount)
                .forEach(list::remove);

            return new Basket(list);
        }

        public void printBasket() {
            books.forEach(
                book -> System.out.println("Book number " + book.getbooknumber())
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks amazing haha

Answer (score 1):

Using `LinkedHashSet` to get unique elements and keep insertion order:

```
static void removeDifferent(List<Book> books, int quantityToRemove) {
    Set<Book> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>(books);
    Iterator<Book> iterator = unique.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext() && quantityToRemove-- > 0) {
        books.remove(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

output:

```
[1: book1, 1: book1, 3: book3]
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this code works for you. It checks if removed list contains the item, then it removes it if it does not contain it and before removing it also adds it to the removed list. Until the count of removed list is equal to the required number to remove

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> books = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"book1", "book1", "book1", "book2", "book3"}));
        System.out.println(books);

        books = remove(2, books);
        System.out.println(books);
    }

    private static List<String> remove(int i, List<String> books) {
        List<String> removed = new ArrayList<>();

        books.removeIf(b -> {
            boolean remove = !removed.contains(b) && removed.size() < i;
            if(remove) removed.add(b);
            return remove;
        });
        return books;
    }
}
```

[image]